# What does "absolute merit" mean in the sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

The following part is quoted from *Byways in Bookland* by W. H. Davenport Adams in the 19th century, and I can’t understand the **“absolute merits”** here in the sentence. In addition, the last sentence of this paragraph is also somewhat puzzling for me. Does the author means that the poetic talent that Hon. Hallam Tennyson had inherited is like a punishment rather than award for him? Would you please explain them for me, thank you!

> The works of the present Lord Lytton and of Mr. Aubrey de Vere are too well appreciated to need much characterization. *These writers would no doubt deprecate any comparison of their products with those of the first Lord Lytton and Sir Aubrey de Vere, but it is one from which, on the score of **absolute merit**, they would have no occasion to shrink.* Mr. Oscar Wilde and Mr. Eric Mackay have written verse, no doubt, because Lady Wilde and Dr. Charles Mackay wrote verse before them ; and the Hon. Hallam Tennyson has shown, in a rhythmical version of a nursery tale, that some measure of poetic faculty has been meted out to him.

Comment: I think it just means *merit* or *quality* or *objective value*. The author is saying the present writers' merit is sufficient to be compared to their ancestors.

Comment: 'Value taking all factors into account.' But who decides how to weight the necessarily often subjective scores on popularity // grammaticality // fineness of style // overcoming a lack of formal education / a lack of money to buy decent paper / a poor roof / poor lighting ... ?

Comment: In general I guess *absolute merit* means merit, or value, measured on an absolute scale, without comparing to other work, while *relative merit* means that that the value is relative, measured in some context, compared with somebody else.  I don't know exactly what the author is saying about H. Tennyson, but your punishment idea doesn't seem to fit.  Maybe it would help to look at this quotation in context.  Overall I find the idea of comparing against each person's parent pretty irritating but I guess in the field of literary criticism one could find much worse things....

Answer (score 0):

**Absolute** merit is as opposed to **relative** merit.

**Relative** merit is merit by comparison

Relative merit is dismissed by the author in:

> These writers would no doubt deprecate any comparison of their products with those of the first Lord Lytton and Sir Aubrey de Vere,

Absolute merit is merit that (in this case, their works) possess on a scale of, for example, 1 to 100.

Answer (score -1):

As for the last sentence: "meted out" usually refers to punishment these days, but it can also refer to reward, or talent. [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mete#English) says:

> allot (especially punishment, reward etc.)

Comment: Is this relevant to OP's question?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: absolutely. Reading between the lines, the OP is obviously puzzled by the phrase "meted out", thinking that it can only be applied to punishments.